# Binding to item instead of property inside list box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF list box, I'm currently using a visibility converter bound to Returns on the current item.
However instead of passing in the value of returns I want to pass in the object.

I've tried using / instead of Path=Returns but it no longer calls the converter.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<ListBox Name="BetsListBox" BorderThickness="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Wagers}"  FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="12">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding Path=UnitStake, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding Path=WagerType}" Margin="5,0" />
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding Path=CalculatedStake, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}"  />
                <StackPanel Margin="-5,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=Returns,Converter={StaticResource BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Text=", Bet Returns"  FontFamily="Arial"  FontStretch="ExtraCondensed" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding PotentialReturns, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStretch="ExtraCondensed" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the Binding directly?

Edit:

My bad, forgot to remove the comma:

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}"
```

Comment: I get unexpected token when I do that:Error 44 ' ,Converter={StaticResource BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}' is not valid. Markup extensions require only spaces between the markup extension name and the first parameter. Cannot have comma or equals sign before the first parameter

Comment: Not removing the comma was what was catching me out the whole time I've been trying this too, I am an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

In binding, when you don't specify the path it means bind to current `DataContext` which in this case is respective item from ListBox's `ItemsSource` :

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource 
    BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `"{Binding}"` if there is nothing else in the markup for that `Binding`, but if you want to add a `Converter`, then you'll have to use the `.` notation to say 'this object':

```
<StackPanel Margin="-5,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource 
    BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

You can find out more from the [Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

To clarify the situation, there are a number of ways that you can data bind to a whole object in XAML:

If you have a comma here, then you *will* need to use the `.` notation to avoid a compilation error:

```
<StackPanel Margin="-5,0" Visibility="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource 
    BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

If you have no comma here, then you will *not* need to use the `.` notation:

```
<StackPanel Margin="-5,0" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource 
    BetWagerPotentialReturnToVisibilityConverter1}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Also, setting the `Path` (as in the original example) is optional and this keyword can be omitted (as in the two examples above).

Comment: Just want to clarify, is `Path` really required when using Converter? I just tried simple binding like : `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBool}}">` and I get my textblock's datacontext passed just fine to converter.

Comment: "then you'll have to use the . notation". Actually that's not true. The binding also works without explicitly writing `Path=.`. Like shown in the other answers.

Comment: @har07, no you don't have to use `Path`, but I added because *you* had it in your example. I updated my answer to be clear.